# How to check if file (image) exists in TypoScript?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, file-exists

I'd like to check if a certain file (image) actually exists and make the output dependent on the result. How to do that in TypoScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the fastest solution will be using `userFunc` condition as described in the [docs](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#condition-userfunc).

The sample is self-explanatory, so there's no need to put it here.

Answer (score 0):

Because the link to the docs is outdated, and I came here via a search engine, I would like to link to a possible solution. Here we go: [Typoscript - Link a file only if it exists using URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176829/typoscript-link-a-file-only-if-it-exists-using-url#51273297)