# Typoscript filelink - Hide label

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I create a link to a file using `filelink`. I getting the name of the file using another Templavoila FCE `field_title` ([see precedent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176829/typoscript-link-a-file-only-if-it-exists-using-url)).

What I want is pretty simple, **I want to display only the icon, not the label**.
I managed to display no text, but I still get the `<a></a>`.

I tried using `labelStdWrap` or `labelStdWrap.override`, but so far nothing worked. I found in the [TsRef](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/7.6/Functions/Filelink/) that you can hide the icon, but nothing is said about hiding the label.

Here is the Typoscript :

```
lib.field_datasheet = TEXT
lib.field_datasheet {
  value {
    field = field_title
    wrap = |.pdf
    }
  filelink {
    path = /fileadmin/datasheet/
    icon_link = 1
    }
 }
```

The HTML code I get is that :

```
<a href="/fileadmin/datasheet/Title.pdf">
 <img src="/typo3/sysext/frontend/Resources/Public/Icons/FileIcons/pdf.gif">
</a>
<a href="/fileadmin/datasheet/Title.pdf">Title.pdf</a>
```

And it's the entire last line I don't want to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the label with link in this way:

```
lib.field_datasheet = TEXT
lib.field_datasheet {
  value {
    field = field_title
    wrap = |.pdf
  }
  filelink {
    path = /fileadmin/datasheet/
    icon = 1
    icon_link = 1
    file.cObject = TEXT
  }
}
```

`file.cObject = TEXT` will remove the label and link, but the icon and its link will be unaffected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've just edited my question (but too late) to be more precise.
It works but a <a></a> is still generated, and to be clean, I'd like that not to be.

Comment: I've edited my answer to answer your edited question now :)

Answer (score 0):

you have two options to clear an earlier set property:

**This will remove the property (and subproperties) from the typoscript definition**:

```
lableStdWrap >
```

this obviously also removes all further stdWrap functions

**and this will set an empty string**:

```
labelStdWrap =
```

be aware: this might result in no wrapping, so you loose more than just the text.

You can use these in combination with typoscript conditions, but not with condition wraps (`.if...`, `.override`, `.ifEmpty`, ...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I just added in the question, I also want to not have the <a></a> around the label. It's that part which is more difficult.
I've tried what you said without success, but maybe I did it wrong, it didn't delete the <a></a> tag.